# Signature function in field extension is onto

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I need help with this problem. 
Suppose $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a separable field extension. We know that there exists $\theta$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. We also know that if $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n$ are the complex roots of $\min(\mathbb{Q},\theta)$ then the immersions $\sigma_i:K\to \mathbb{C}$ are given by $\sigma_i(\theta) = \theta_i$.
Suppose that $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ are **real** immersions and define
$$ \operatorname{sign}: K^\times \to \{ \pm 1 \}^r $$
where $\operatorname{sign}(\alpha) = (\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma_1(\alpha)),\ldots,\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma_r(\alpha)))$.
I need to prove that this $\operatorname{sign}$ function is onto, i.e, all of the $2^r$ signs are taken. Can you help me with some guidance or hint? I am really confused with this. I understand the roots of the minimal polynomial are permuted by the $\sigma_i$ and I believe I need to associate this problem with the permutation sign (the permutation of the roots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some approximation result. If $K$ has $r$ real and $2s$ imaginary embeddings, then the image of $K$ under the natural map $\Phi$
from $K$ to $\Bbb R^r\times
\Bbb C^s$ is dense. Given this, there will be elements of $K$
such that $|\sigma_j(\alpha)-\epsilon_j|<1$ for all $j$ where the $\epsilon_j$ are
your favourite choices from $\{\pm1\}$. This $\alpha$ will have the right signs.

To see this density result, note that the closure of the image of $\Phi$
will certainly be a real vector subspace of $\Bbb R^r\times
\Bbb C^s$. If is is a proper subspace, then there will be a linear dependence
between the embeddings of $K$ into $\Bbb C$ and that would contradict
Dedekind's theorem on linear independence of characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The hint it was given was: show that it suffices to find elements with $sign(\alpha) = (1,\ldots,-1,\ldots,1)$  (i.e, exactly one $-1$ in one entry and $1$'s in the remaining entries). Do you know how can I prove such elements exist?